# How to use pipreqs to create requirements.txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies

I am trying to use the pipreqs package to generate a requirements.txt file. [Following the documentation's examples](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) I have been unable to make it work.

It seems simple enough, the documentation tells me to use this command in the terminal:

```
$ pipreqs /home/project/location
```

In my case, this is the location of my project:

```
$ pipreqs /Users/ep9k/Desktop/UVA\ Big\Deal
```

And I get this error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/UVA BigDeal/requirements.txt'
```

The error message is correct, there is no requirements.txt file in that directory. I am trying to use pipreqs to create the requirements.txt file.

Reading the documentation, pipreqs is supposed to scan a python file for import statements and build the requirements.txt document based on that. So I tried this as well, with the file I want pipreqs to scan:

```
$ pipreqs /Users/ep9k/Desktop/UVA\ Big\Deal/1FigrFunctions.py
```

and I received this error, which is pretty much the same as above:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/UVA BigDeal/1FigrFunctions.py/requirements.txt'
```

I am sure the solution is obvious. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated - Github Copilot just hallucinated your username into my code completion: "        input=(
            Path("/Users/ep9k/Desktop/overview_mosaic.json"),
            Path("/Users/ep9k/Desktop/mosaic.json"),
        )" :)

Answer (score 21):

I answered my own question. I think the errors were due to there being a bunch of files in the directory I was trying to run pipreqs on. To solve this problem, I created a new empty directory called "test" and put the file I wanted to generate requirements.txt for in that directory. So there is only one file in my new "test" directory. Then I ran the command as follows:

```
$ pipreqs /Users/ep9k/Desktop/test
```

and it worked. Really simple...

Comment: For me it creates an empty requirements file, running the command from inside a tensorflow environment. To fix this I had to create it inside the project folder only.

Answer (score 15):

I discovered how to solve this error using below steps-
If you want to specify full path for your python file, use this -

```
pipreqs --encoding utf-8 "C:\Users\username\Downloads\Bl_container\training\fold\"
```

Also, the python file should be alone in the folder.

If you are currently in your python file directory, use this -

```
pipreqs --encoding utf-8 "./"
```

Using encoding to get rid of the map error.
Make sure that you are not connected to any VPN or you may get **HTTPConnection** error.

Answer (score 11):

Use Pigar instead, I have a lot of problems with `pipreqs`.

https://github.com/Damnever/pigar

```
pip install pigar
```

Then, go to the dir of your project from the console and use this:

```
pigar generate
```

This is going to generate a requeriments.txt file in your directory, like this:

```
# Automatically generated by https://github.com/damnever/pigar.

# Editable install with no version control (mysql-connector-python==8.0.33)
-e c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql_connector_python-8.0.33-py3.10.egg-info
opencv-python==4.7.0.72
openpyxl==3.1.2
pandas==2.0.1
PySide2==5.15.2.1
```

Comment: Sorry, i forget this. You can install the requirements with this: 
pip install -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried:

```
$ pipreqs --encoding utf-8 "/Users/ep9k/Desktop/UVA/Big/Deal" --force
```

I've managed to create requirement.txt for multiple .py files in one dir.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `pipreqs --ignore .venv` to create requirements.txt with just the packages you imported in your code. (.venv is the virtual environment folder name).

If you do not ignore that folder in pipreqs command, it will read all the files in .venv and create all the packages and their sub-packages in the requirements.txt

Answer (score 2):

First Install pipreqs (Just to Ensure):

```
pip install pipreqs
```

Then Run this Command:

```
python -m pipreqs.pipreqs
```

Comment: Python3 worked for me: python3 -m pipreqs.pipreqs