# How to list all python packages used by a script in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

There's a few of these question I've read through, but they all seem to link to methods exclusively for python 2.x and I'm working in python 3.x.

I have a python file, call it test.py, it has a number of package imports (eg. import numpy as np) but it also imports some other files, lets call them subTest1.py and subTest2.py. Each of the subTest files have their own imports (possibly both other files and packages). Is there an automated way to get a list of all packages required to run the route script (test.py)?

I'm aware that pip freeze shows me every packages installed, but that's not what I'm looking for - there could be a package installed that isn't required to run the test.py script.

**Questions that are similar but python 2.x:**

[Return a list of imported Python modules used in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572582/return-a-list-of-imported-python-modules-used-in-a-script)

[Get all modules/packages used by a python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796968/get-all-modules-packages-used-by-a-python-project)

**Packages that seem to be specific to python 2.x:**

snakefood

pipreqs

Where pipreqs fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda36\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\anaconda36\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda36\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\pipreqs.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda36\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 396, in main
    init(args)
  File "c:\anaconda36\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 341, in init
    extra_ignore_dirs=extra_ignore_dirs)
  File "c:\anaconda36\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 91, in get_all_imports
    raise exc
  File "c:\anaconda36\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 77, in get_all_imports
    tree = ast.parse(contents)
  File "c:\anaconda36\envs\tensorflow\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 49
    print vsize
              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Comment: if you are using PyCharm IDE, there is a plugin called requirements that does that per project scope

Comment: @ElSheikh I wish I was. I'm using anaconda... that's a good point though, I'll see if anaconda has something similar

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `pipreqs` package. ([Docs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs))

To Install:

```sh
pip3 install pipreqs
```

Usage:

```
pipreqs ./your_script_directory
```

It produces a `requirements.txt` file in your script directory with all the dependencies used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does pipreqs support python3? When trying to use it, it seems to fail

Comment: Yes it does. What do you mean fail? any errors or invalid modules in requirements.txt?

Comment: It fails to run, with the error: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. I assumed that's due to python3 requiring print be used with parentheses and python2 not requiring them. I installed pipreqs using pip install, so I should have gotten the most recent version

Comment: @user6916458, You should use `pip3` instead of `pip`. You pip might still point to python2.

Comment: I've added the entire output from pipreqs to the post

Comment: When using pip3 I get the same error. (I uninstalled pipreqs using pip uninstall..., and then reinstalled with pip3...)

Comment: @user6916458, Try creating a new conda environement like `conda create -n myenv python=3.8` and then running the above.

Comment: I've tried making a new environment and running the script again and it has the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201966/discussion-between-rithin-chalumuri-and-user6916458).

Comment: The package is also available with `conda`:

`conda install pipreqs`

Comment: This doesn't appear to consider imported packages that were not originally installed through pip. Perhaps obvious from the name, but a problem for the use I was looking at.

Comment: `pigar` works better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71445496/1599699

Answer (score 0):

I have found this script in the google and it seems to be working,I have updated it for python 3,(just print function),
I have tested it and it lists modules, but I believe it goes too deep under the modules but worth trying.

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
f = ModuleFinder()

# Run the main script
f.run_script('test.py')

# Get names of all the imported modules
names = list(f.modules.keys())

# Get a sorted list of the root modules imported
basemods = sorted(set([name.split('.')[0] for name in names]))
# Print it nicely
print("\n".join(basemods))
```

just change `test.py` in any filename you want to check.
and then run the script from terminal

```
python module_finder_script.py
```

let me know if it helps.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this --

1. Install gunicorn --   `pip3 install gunicorn`
2. Inside your project directory, type -- `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`

This (requirements.txt) will give you the list of all the packages used inside the project directory.

Comment: This lists the python packages installed in the current environment *not* the python packages used by the script.